# How to alter a class attribute in a child class, and use it in a method defined in the parent class?

Tags: python, inheritance, attributes

I can't seem to find a set of search keywords that provide an answer to this question. I'd like to create a parent class in which a method that uses a class attribute is defined. The child classes will define the values of the class attribute for that child class, using it when calling the method defined in the parent class. How can I do this?

[EDIT: Why do I want to do this? Note that yes, I could create an **instance** attribute that accomplishes the behavioral goal as shown below. But I want to do this with a **class** attribute because the code below is just toy example. In my production code I will be creating many thousands of instances of the child classes, and the attribute itself is a large array of data. To my understanding, if I use an **instance** class it would be a huge waste of memory.]

For example, I want something like this:

```py
class Parent:
    multiplier = None
    def use_it(self, x):
        return Parent.multiplier * x

class Boy(Parent):
    multiplier = 2


class Girl(Parent):
    multiplier = 3


boy = Boy()
print(boy.use_it(10))

girl = Girl()
print(girl.use_it(10))
```

That would produce this output:

```py
20
30
```

The traceback:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/scratch/test.py in <module>
     13 
     14 boy = Boy()
---> 15 print(boy.use_it(10))
     16 
     17 girl = Girl()

~/scratch/test.py in use_it(self, x)
      2     multiplier = None
      3     def use_it(self, x):
----> 4         return Parent.multiplier * x
      5 
      6 class Boy(Parent):

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Futhermore, if I try to redefine the class attribute when definining the child attribute, it redefines it for all classes that inherit from that parent, not just that specific child class. See this example:

```py
class Parent:
    multiplier = None
    def use_it(self, x):
        return Parent.multiplier * x

class Boy(Parent):
    Parent.multiplier = 2


class Girl(Parent):
    Parent.multiplier = 3


boy = Boy()
print(boy.use_it(10))

girl = Girl()
print(girl.use_it(10))
```

Output:

```py
30
30
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: The code you have shown does exactly what you asked for. You just need to add the  missing `self` parameter to `use_it` and access `multiplier` as `self.multiplier`. Did you try your code before asking?

Comment: I've expanded on my question, fixed a couple types, added tracebacks, and explained why I want to do what I'm trying to do. Kemp, I'm not lazy. I've tried many variations of the code. I accidentally left out the ```self``` argument in the ```use_it()``` toy example (and corrected that in the original post). But changing ```multiplier``` to ```self.multiplier``` is not the solution, as that creates an instance attribute, not a class attribute (actually, it creates an error, since it isn't contained in a ```__init__()``` method).

Comment: Ok, so using `self.multiplier` *is* the way to go (see my answer). It does *not* create an instance attribute unless you write to it.

Comment: Ahhh. Nice. Thanks, quamrana and Kemp!

Comment: PS - I see now that changing ```multiplier``` to ```self.multiplier``` was indeed part of the solution, but on my initial reading I though Kemp was suggesting that I change that in the child class definitions, not only in the parent class definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you made a few mistakes. I would say that your first revision of the question was closer to working. This is what you want:

```py
class Parent:
    def use_it(self, x):
        return self.multiplier * x

class Boy(Parent):
    multiplier = 2


class Girl(Parent):
    multiplier = 3


boy = Boy()
print(boy.use_it(10))


girl = Girl()
print(girl.use_it(10))
```

Output

```
20
30
```

Note how you don't need to define `multiplier` for the `Parent` class because you intend for every derived class to define one itself.